# I get this error when I try to register a new user. 'The department id must be an integer.'

Tags: sql, laravel, xampp

I get this error when I try to register a new user: 'The department id must be an integer'. All the answers I'm receiving are helpful just that I get confused at times. So I've added more codes for clarification purposes. I have been battling around for some hours now. Here is the migration file.

```
                        Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
                        $table->bigIncrements('department_id');
                        $table->integer('department_name');
                        $table->integer('department_code')->unique();
                        $table->text('department_discription')->nullable();
                        $table->tinyInteger('department_status')->default(1);
                        $table->softDeletes();
                        $table->timestamps();
```

This is the DepartmentController codes

```
        <?php
        
        namespace App\Http\Controllers;
        
        use App\Http\Requests\CreateDepartmentRequest;
        use App\Http\Requests\UpdateDepartmentRequest;
        use App\Repositories\DepartmentRepository;
        use App\Http\Controllers\AppBaseController;
        use Illuminate\Http\Request;
        use Flash;
        use Response;
        
        class DepartmentController extends AppBaseController
        {
            /** @var  DepartmentRepository */
            private $departmentRepository;
        
            public function __construct(DepartmentRepository $departmentRepo)
            {
                $this->departmentRepository = $departmentRepo;
            }
        
            /**
             * Display a listing of the Department.
             *
             * @param Request $request
             *
             * @return Response
             */
            public function index(Request $request)
            {
                $departments = $this->departmentRepository->all();
        
                return view('departments.index')
                    ->with('departments', $departments);
            }
        
            /**
             * Show the form for creating a new Department.
             *
             * @return Response
             */
            public function create()
            {
                return view('departments.create');
            }
        
            /**
             * Store a newly created Department in storage.
             *
             * @param CreateDepartmentRequest $request
             *
             * @return Response
             */
            public function store(CreateDepartmentRequest $request)
            {
                $input = $request->all();
        
                $department = $this->departmentRepository->create($input);
        
                Flash::success('Department saved successfully.');
        
                return redirect(route('departments.index'));
            }
        
            /**
             * Display the specified Department.
             *
             * @param int $id
             *
             * @return Response
             */
            public function show($id)
            {
                $department = $this->departmentRepository->find($id);
        
                if (empty($department)) {
                    Flash::error('Department not found');
        
                    return redirect(route('departments.index'));
                }
        
                return view('departments.show')->with('department', $department);
            }
        
            /**
             * Show the form for editing the specified Department.
             *
             * @param int $id
             *
             * @return Response
             */
            public function edit($id)
            {
                $department = $this->departmentRepository->find($id);
        
                if (empty($department)) {
                    Flash::error('Department not found');
        
                    return redirect(route('departments.index'));
                }
        
                return view('departments.edit')->with('department', $department);
            }
        
            /**
             * Update the specified Department in storage.
             *
             * @param int $id
             * @param UpdateDepartmentRequest $request
             *
             * @return Response
             */
            public function update($id, UpdateDepartmentRequest $request)
            {
                $department = $this->departmentRepository->find($id);
        
                if (empty($department)) {
                    Flash::error('Department not found');
        
                    return redirect(route('departments.index'));
                }
        
                $department = $this->departmentRepository->update($request->all(), $id);
        
                Flash::success('Department updated successfully.');
        
                return redirect(route('departments.index'));
            }
        
            /**
             * Remove the specified Department from storage.
             *
             * @param int $id
             *
             * @throws \Exception
             *
             * @return Response
             */
            public function destroy($id)
            {
                $department = $this->departmentRepository->find($id);
        
                if (empty($department)) {
                    Flash::error('Department not found');
        
                    return redirect(route('departments.index'));
                }
        
                $this->departmentRepository->delete($id);
        
                Flash::success('Department deleted successfully.');
        
                return redirect(route('departments.index'));
            }
        }
```

here is the department code

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

/**
 * Class Departments
 * @package App\Models
 * @version September 21, 2020, 4:31 pm UTC
 *
 * @property integer $department_name
 * @property integer $department_code
 * @property string $department_discription
 * @property boolean $department_status
 */
class Departments extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'departments';
    
    const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';


    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];



    public $fillable = [
        'department_name',
        'department_code',
        'department_discription',
        'department_status'
    ];

    
    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'department_id' => 'integer',
        'department_name' => 'integer',
        'department_code' => 'integer',
        'department_discription' => 'string',
        'department_status' => 'boolean'
    ];

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [
        'department_name' => 'required|integer',
        'department_code' => 'required|integer',
        'department_discription' => 'nullable|string',
        'department_status' => 'required|boolean',
        'deleted_at' => 'nullable',
        'created_at' => 'nullable',
        'updated_at' => 'nullable'
    ];
}
```

Comment: `$table->bigIncrements('id');` or `$table->id();` Auto-incrementing UNSIGNED BIGINT (primary key) equivalent column.

Comment: validation is failing it would seem

Comment: please provide the code that cause the error, registering, and user model and migration

Answer (score 1):

in  your migration, try make 'department_id' the primary key [declaratively](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-indexes):

```
 $table->primary('department_id');
```

then (like sta said in the comment) in your Department model:

```
 protected $primaryKey = "department_id";
```

or change it's name to just 'id'

Answer (score 1):

you should create a depatment like this:

```
\App\Models\Department::create([
       'department_name' => 1,
       'department_code' => 1,
       'department_discription' => 'first department',
       'department_status' => 1
   ]);
```

don't forget to add columns name to fillable variable in your Department model

Comment: Here is the department model public $fillable = [
        'department_name',
        'department_code',
        'department_discription',
        'department_status'

Comment: the department_id column is "auto-increment", have you assigned any value to this? to be more clear, please share your code completely.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are going to need to change your department_id field in the db.
Create a new migration and for your department_id key, set it like this.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('department_id')->autoIncrement();
```

That should take care of your issue. What it will do is maintain the integrity of your db in the event that you need to add a relationship because it will create that field the same type as the id on other tables (unsignedBigInteger), but it will also autoIncrement the field.